# Error running after installing ncl on Mac1

Tags: zsh, ncl

I'm a user using ncl in m1mac. I'm trying to run it after installing it through Anaconda, but a command not found error occurs.
I've also confirmed that ncl is installed in the anaconda3 folder, and it's activated well with conda activation

```
(l) lsh@isuhyeons-MacBook-Air ~ % ncl ha.ncl 
zsh: command not found: ncl
```

I looked up the official website and various GitHub, but I can't solve it
I'd appreciate it if you could solve it

Comment: How did you confirm that ncl is in your PATH?